# D3 Collide, Charge & Force X or Y contradict one another?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Does anyone have any advice on how I can implement gravity to the center where the biggest nodes go to the middle and smaller nodes are on the outside? Collide does not seem to work at all and nodes tend to overlap. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

```
    const simulation = d3.forceSimulation().alphaDecay(0.01)
        .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }).strength(0.002))
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().distanceMax(height/2).strength(-400))
        .force("x", d3.forceX().x(width/2).strength(0.005))
        .force("y", d3.forceY().y(height/2).strength(0.005))
        .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) {return d.radius + 5; }).strength(1).iterations(10));
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: "Collide, Charge & Force X or Y contradict one another?" Yes - the force is a compromise between all the forces applied. You could apply the strength of forceX and forceY more strongly for large nodes (same as you do for the radius but for strength in this case).